# How to delete order item from order object?

Tags: orders, varien

How to delete order item from order object? For example:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(1);

foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $order->removeByItemId($item->getId());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is more of a hack**. Warning: you could accidentally delete items if you're not careful.

The `getAllItems` method filters items out of the item collection and returns it. 
In order to filter items out of the `getAllItems` array you simply need to mark the desired items in the collection as deleted:

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $item->isDeleted(true);
}
```

Subsequent calls to `getAllItems` will return items not marked as deleted.

Now, where **things get hairy** is that if you call `save` on that item, **it will delete it**. This is dangerous.

So, what I suggest instead, is that you build your own collection with only the data that you know that you want. For instance:

```
$collection = new Varien_Data_Collection();
```

And then populate it:

```
foreach($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
    //some condition
    $collection->addItem($item);
}
```

Now your new collection only contains the data that you want, and you can hand that around.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the question edit. However, I would like just to remove the item from the object not really delete it. Maybe I did not put my question right.

Comment: Why would you remove it from the object? What is the end goal?

Comment: I am making cloned order objects in order to pass them to mailer class. Now some of these mails that should be sent need to contain some items while others don't. I want to loop through order items and make several cloned order objects with specific items in them.

Comment: If I can post a sub question (regarding this approach), how to remove all items from order?

Comment: On any collection you can remove items from the collection by calling `removeItemByKey` but the trick is knowing what the key is...

Comment: Yep, another loop then...